# How to use Raspberry Pi GPIO ports in ROS 2?

Tags: ros2, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi running ROS 2 in Ubuntu. How do you access the Pi's GPIO ports? Is there a library? I'm not sure if I'm running into a ROS 2 or C++ issue.

I've had trouble importing the `wiringPi` package as there was no `.cmake`.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindwiringPi.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "wiringPi",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "wiringPi" with any
  of the following names:

    wiringPiConfig.cmake
    wiringpi-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "wiringPi" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "wiringPi_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "wiringPi" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Is it common practice to use someone's `pigpio` repo as a ROS 2 package?

#### Resources

- http://wiringpi.com/
- http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html
- https://github.com/search?q=ros2%20gpio&type=repositories
- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117591/controlling-raspberry-pi-gpio-with-c-and-python/117592#117592

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: I tried to answer it assuming a beginner level learner. @Tully

Comment: Thanks @Robotawi, you did do your best to provide an answer that could answer one interpretation of the question. There are lots of ways to solve this problem. You've picked one, which I agree is generally reasonable for a potential interpretation of the question. This question does not meet our standards for a good question which is why I closed it. Please read through the links in my comment above for more info. You spent a bunch of time and potentially others will spend a bunch of time trying to answer this question that cannot be effectively answered and would better serve a good question.

Comment: Thanks for revising this. But I'm not going to reopen it. It's now a duplicate of your other question https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105602/how-do-you-import-an-external-library-like-wiringpi-into-your-ros-2-project

Comment: This is your linking problem. Please add this new information there too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question about using Rasperry Pi GPIO ports in ROS 2 is an example of combining hardware controller with robotics software frameworks. I mean they are separate, but can be integrated to serve application purpose. Let's break down the integration process in a simple way.

**ROS 2**: is a framework used in robotics for managing communication and an hardware interfacing.

**Raspberry Pi**: a computer equipped with general purpose input/output (GPIO) pins. Thosse pins can interface with various electronic components like LEDs, sensors, and motor drives. We can program those pins with Python or C++.

#### The Integration

Integrating Ras Pi's GPIO functionality with ROS 2 involves creating a ROS 2 node which code interacts with the GPIO pin. This node serves as a bridge, allowing ROS 2 ecosystem to communicate with the Raspberry Pi. **Notice** we can write code that talks with Ras Pi with nothing to do with ROS at all.

#### Minimal examples:

**(1) Simple Python LED control script**

Controlling a LED using the Ras Pi's GPIO:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

led_pin = 17  # GPIO pin to which a LED is connected

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(1)
    GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(1)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

**(2) Make the previous minimal example a ROS 2 node**

Notice how the code that uses the GPIO integrates within the code that makes a ROS 2 node.

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

class LEDBlinkerNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('led_blinker')
        self.led_pin = 17
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.led_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.timer_callback)

    def timer_callback(self):
        GPIO.output(self.led_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1) 
        GPIO.output(self.led_pin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1) 

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    led_blinker_node = LEDBlinkerNode()
    rclpy.spin(led_blinker_node)

    GPIO.cleanup()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Those examples are about the idea of integrating separate modules to serve the purpose the application. The key takeaway is the adaptability of these systems. Start simple and keep going!

---

I did not go into the parts of the dependencies installation, which is usually available in documentations. If this is needed, I will enhance the reply.

Comment: Have you ever used wiringPi with C? I got the `gpio` commands working in the terminal and reflect on the physical wiring but I can't get it to work using the wiringPi library.

Answer (score 0):

Pi GPIO library doesn't interact with ROS2 in any way I know of. Just use it as you would any library. The Pi GPIO deamon doesn't seem to impact ROS2 function either.